# Pra que serve o atributo Role?

Tags: html, html5

Já vi um código onde tinha essa tag `Role` em um `form`, porém não entendi seu uso.

Algo como:

```
<form role="search">
</form>
```

Para que serve a tag `role` no HTML5 ?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/role-attribute/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Esse atributo serve para dar mais semântica aos elementos de documentos baseados em marcação, a [partir de 2013](http://www.w3.org/TR/role-attribute/) a [W3](http://www.w3.org) passou a recomendar o seu uso. Em português *Role* significa *Papel*, num sentido de cargo/oficio daquele elemento.

Com essa semântica os navegadores podem prover mais acessibilidade para alguns elementos, já que eles passam a conhecer o papel dos elementos no documento.

### Exemplo de uso

Para usar o atributo `Role` deve declarar o *namespace* do [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml), seja o documento um HTML 4.01, HTML 5, XHTML ou XML. Isso é simples e já bastante conhecido de quem utilizava XHTML.

Veja o exemplo de como incluir o *namespace* em um documento HTML 5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt-BR">
...
```

No exemplo acima, foi usado um *namespace* sem nome. Mas como ele pode ser declarado em documentos XML, você pode dar um *namespace* com um nome específico, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<exemplo
    xmlns="http://algum.lugar.com/a/especificacao/de/exemplo"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
```

Depois de incluído o *namespace*, basta usar o atributo `Role` nos elementos (*tags*) que deseja agregar alguma semântica extra.

O valor do atributo é uma *string* contendo um ou mais elementos separados por espaço. Cada elemento é uma referência para um termo de um vocabulário, que é definido em [RDF](http://www.w3.org/RDF/).

Existem três formas de especificar esta referência: um termo do vocabulário padrão, um [CURIE](http://www.w3.org/TR/curie/) ou um IRI absoluto.

Os *termos do vocabulário padrão* são os termos definidos no *namespace* padrão (o *namespace* declarado sem nome), que normalmente é o [RDF](http://www.w3.org/RDF/) do próprio [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml), que citamos acima.

Só de incluir o [*namespace*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-role/#a_module_qname) do XHTML, você pode usar os termos definidos no seu vocabulário, que podem ser consultados no Vocabulário do XHTML. Este vocabulário inclui, por exemplo, o termo `alert`, usado em elementos que representam mensagens importantes e, normalmente, emitidas devido algum acontecimento na aplicação.

Neste caso, podemos aplicar este termo a uma `<div>` (ou outro elemento qualquer), como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<div role="alert">Usuário cadastrado com sucesso.</div>
```

Mas, além dos termos definidos no vocabulário padrão, podemos usar termos definidos em vocabulários carregados por outro *namespace*, como neste exemplo, que usa o recurso de CURIE (URI compacto):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:educ="http://www.exemplo.org/roles/educacao#">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Disciplina de Álgebra</h1>
    <div>
        Professor(a):
        <span role="educ:professor">João da Silva</span>
    </div>
    ...
```

Uma última forma de especificar o valor de uma `Role` é pelo seu IRI absoluto, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<div role="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab/#alert">
    Usuário cadastrado com sucesso
</div>
```

**Vocabulário do XHTML**

O Vocabulário de termos do XHTML está dividido em três partes:

- Vocabulário de Metainformações
- Vocabulário de Papeis do XHTML
- Vocabulário de [ARIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAI-ARIA)

O [**vocabulário de Metainformações**](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#XHTMLMetaInformationModule) normalmente é usado nos elementos do `HEAD` do documento HTML. Ele possui vários papeis que representam *links* para outros documentos (*resources*) com significados próprios, como o *link* para a primeira página de uma série de páginas, *link* para última página, link para página principal, *link* para página de ajuda, link para página de glossário, etc. Além disso possui o papel *copyright* para indicar que o elemento contém as notas de direito de cópia.

O [**vocabulário de Papeis do XHTML**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/PF/XTech/HTML5/RoleAttribute#Items_from_the_XHTML_Role_Module) possui alguns papeis de propósito geral para documentos de hipertexto, tais como: banner, conteúdo complementar (*complementary*), bloco de meta-informações do conteúdo da página (*contentinfo*), a definição de um termo (*definition*), especificação de conteúdo principal da página (*main*), conteúdo de navegação (*navigation*), nota extra (*note*) ou elemento reservado para buscas (*search*).

Alguns destes papeis já possuem elementos do próprio HTML 5 e HTML 5.1 que podem ser mais adequados para uso, como a tag `<nav>` para navegação, a tag `<main>` (do HTML 5.1) para o conteúdo principal, ou a tag `<aside>` para conteúdo complementar.

Estes termos estão no vocabulário pois eles podem ser usados por qualquer XML, não necessariamente um HTML. No caso do XML, pode ser que não seja possível utilizar as *tags* do HTML em função de seu protocolo de construção.

Já o [**vocabulário de ARIA**](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#WAIARIA) é usado para apontar o papel de elementos de aplicações de acessibilidade rica, como menus, caixas de mensagens, botões, *comboboxes*, *checkboxes*, *radioboxes*, textos de cabeçalho, abas, *logs* e muitos outros papeis.

Referências:

- [Role Attribute dando mais sentido ao HTML](http://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/role-attribute-dando-mais-sentido-ao-html.html)
- [XHTML Vocabulary](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#XHTMLRoleVocabulary)

Answer (score 11):

É usado mais para acessibilidade - [ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAI-ARIA) - ela fornece contexto ao elemento. Mas também pode ser usado para criar situações mais complexas, facilitar alguma análise pelo servidor ou dar uma informação que permita uma melhor adaptação da página ao dispositivo onde ela está sendo mostrada.

É uma forma de dar mais semântica para a página que é fundamental para quem tem dificuldade pessoal ou no dispositivo que está usando, além de informar melhor para ferramentas interpretarem a estrutura da página. Note que é diferente de dar semântica ao conteúdo propriamente dito.

No seu exemplo provavelmente está indicando que este formulário é usado para fazer uma pesquisa. Isto pode ajudar o usuário que é cego, por exemplo, saber que é para isto que aquilo deve ser usado. Uma ferramenta de análise sempre é "cega", se ela consegue aproveitar um formulário de busca de alguma forma ela precisa saber onde este formulário está e o desenvolvedor pode informar com este atributo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).